# Plotting circles and arc without segmentation (PLT format)

Tags: autocad

I'm having problems plotting vector objects such as arcs and circles from Autodesk without forcing them into set of lines. PLT (HPGL) file format supports both circles and arcs defined through various means, but for some reason, the output uses just lines.

The drawing I've created is really simple, just for testing purposes
[image: Arc and Circle drawing]

and the output from plotting (I've separated commands into single lines so it's more readable)

```
.(;.I81;;17:.N;19:IN;
SC;
PU;
RO90;
IP;
IW;
VS20,1VS20,2VS20,3VS20,4VS20,5VS20,6VS20,7VS20,8SP1;
PU;
PA0,0;
SP1;
LT;
PA-4985,2256;
PDPA-2985,256,-2985,-1744,-4985,256,-4985,2256;
PUPA-4967,-2572;
PDPA-4862,-2569,-4757,-2563,-4653,-2552,-4549,-2538,-4446,-2520,-4343,-2498,-4241,-2473,-4141,-2443,-4041,-2410,-3943,-2373,-3846,-2333,-3751,-2289,-3657,-2241,-3566,-2190,-3476,-2136,-3388,-2078,-3303,-2017,-3219,-1953,-3139,-1886,-3060,-1816,-2985,-1744;
PUPA-1530,-26;
PDPA-1472,-24,-1414,-18,-1357,-8,-1300,5,-1245,22,-1190,42,-1137,66,-1086,94,-1037,124,-989,158,-944,195,-902,235,-862,277,-825,322,-791,369,-761,419,-733,470,-709,523,-689,577,-672,633,-659,690,-649,747,-644,805,-642,863,-644,921,-649,979,-659,1036,-672,1093,-689,1148,-709,1203,-733,1256,-761,1307,-791,1356,-825,1404,-862,1449,-902,1491,-944,1531,-989,1568,-1037,1602,-1086,1632,-1137,1660,-1190,1684,-1245,1704,-1300,1721,-1357,1734,-1414,1744,-1472,1749,-1530,1751,-1588,1749,-1646,1744,-1703,1734,-1760,1721,-1816,1704,-1870,1684,-1923,1660,-1974,1632,-2024,1602,-2071,1568,-2116,1531,-2158,1491,-2198,1449,-2235,1404,-2269,1356,-2299,1307,-2327,1256,-2351,1203,-2371,1148,-2388,1093,-2401,1036,-2411,979,-2417,921,-2418,863,-2417,805,-2411,747,-2401,690,-2388,633,-2371,577,-2351,523,-2327,470,-2299,419,-2269,369,-2235,322,-2198,277,-2158,235,-2116,195,-2071,158,-2024,124,-1974,94,-1923,66,-1870,42,-1816,22,-1760,5,-1703,-8,-1646,-18,-1588,-24,-1530,-26;
PU;
PA0,0;
SP;
```

Now the [command for circle in PLT](http://cstep.luberth.com/HPGL.pdf) is really simple - `CI` with 3 parameters - center X, Y and radius. Instead it was substituted with bunch of lines.

I've tried various HP printers, but this seems to make no difference as the driver support is always the same, so I settled with HP 7585B. I've also tried increasing quality but this only resulted in more points.

Is there any way to get 1:1 (as by shape) vector graphics from AutoCAD to PLT? Or is there any really simple file format like PLT that would support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DXF instead of PLT. You will got your 1:1 mapping.

Comment: I would like for the format to be human readable and editable, but in the end this would be only nice feature rather than requirement, so if nothing else pops up, I'll go with DFX.